# I want the app to run when it can't connect to the Kafkaappender

Tags: apache-kafka, log4j2

In an application I developed with spring boot, I am sending logs to kafka with the help of log4j2 and kafkaappender.

but if there is a problem in kafka when starting the application or while the application is running, if it cannot connect to kafka, I want the application to continue without giving an error.

```
appender.kafka=org.apache.kafka
appender.kafka.type= kafka
appender.kafka.name= kafkaAppender
appender.kafka.topic= stopic
appender.kafka.property.type=Property
appender.kafka.property.name=bootstrap.servers
appender.kafka.property.value=120.0.0.1:9092
appender.kafka.property2.type=Property
appender.kafka.property2.name=group.id
appender.kafka.property2.value=sgroup


rootLogger.appenderRef.kafka.ref = kafkaAppender
```

the above code is working if there is no problem in the kafka.

Error logs:

```
2023-08-08 00:36:51,775 main ERROR Unable to write to Kafka in appender [kafkaAppender ztopic false bootstrap.servers=120.0.0.1:9092 group.id=sgroup] org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic ztopic not present in metadata after 60000 ms.

00:37:05.119 INFO  com.ulisesbocchio.jasyptspringboot.configuration.EnableEncryptablePropertiesBeanFactoryPostProcessor.postProcessBeanFactory() @48 - Post-processing PropertySource instances
00:37:10.523 INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.handleDisconnections() @977 - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Node -1 disconnected.
00:37:10.524 WARN  org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.processDisconnection() @814 - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Connection to node -1 (/120.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
00:37:10.524 WARN  org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.handleServerDisconnect() @1105 - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Bootstrap broker 120.0.0.1:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
```

Also, I want to send the logs in the application asynchronously.

Thanks

Comment: If you dont want it to error, then don't depend on a network connection for your app to start... Write to a file or syslog, then use tools like fluentd to write to Kafka.

Comment: but in such a case it should not crush the application. There must be a method that handles this.

Comment: Not that I am aware of from log4j config